# how to apply matrix on a different size bitmap

Tags: android, matrix, imageview

i have 2 image views , the first imageview have bitmap with 600 px size second image view have 1024 px bitmap , and i am scaling rotating and moving first image view with matrix , once the user hit a button second image view should have the same size scale and rotation, but because the second imageview have a bigger bitmap i cannot just use

> imageview2.setimagematrix(ImageView1Matrix)

it gives different results, is there anyway i can apply same operations(resize,rotate , translate) on the second imageview frim the first image view matrix?

iam currently trying this but only translate working, scale is not working and i dont know where to start to get the rotation value

```
 float[] values = new float[9];
           MIV1.getValues(values);


          a.setTranslate(values[Matrix.MTRANS_X], values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]);
          */
         RectF r = new RectF(); 
          MIV1.mapRect(r);   

            RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, 1024, 1024);

            a.setRectToRect(drawableRect, r, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
IV2.setImageMatrix(a);
```

Comment: what about Canvas.[pre¦post]Concat() ?

Comment: can you please explain in code, thank you.

Comment: when calling setimagematrix pass concatenated Matrix

Comment: that did not work, not sure if iam doing it correctly here what i did,

Comment: that did not work, not sure if iam doing it correctly here what i did, IV2.setImageMatrix(EmptyMatrix); EmptyMatrix.preconcat(IV1Matrix) ; IV2.setImageMatrix(EmptyMatrix);  i also did the opposite.  can i some how get the first matrix rect postion and rotation and do post operations to make second ImagView same as the first one?

Comment: what is matrix rect postion ?

Comment: did you find a way to do it ?