# Apply matrix from one bitmap to another bitmap with different dimension but with same preview result

Tags: android, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am creating a simple preview application that display different bitmap dimension.

I want to copy the first bitmap matrix and use it to the second bitmap with larger dimension.

I want the preview of the second image be like that of the first one. How to apply the matrix to the second image so that when applied on second image with higher resolution, the preview be same as the first image. I am searching with this for week but didn't find luck so I put it here. Hope I can get help with you.

[image: image details]

Comment: what "matrix" do you mean?

Comment: Hi @pskink android.graphics.Matrix sir. I have matrix in picture 1 (rotate, scale, move).

Comment: so use `postScale`, you can get original `Matrix` not form a `Bitmap` but from an `ImageView` that shows that `Bitmap`

Comment: I found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426700/how-to-apply-matrix-on-a-different-size-bitmap?rq=1                           but no answer.

Comment: did you call `postScale`?

Comment: Yes I did. But i think I did not provide the right value for postscale.

Comment: just call with `sx` == `sy` == 0.1f

Comment: I actually use canvas sir, So i can't get matrix from ImageView

Comment: if you use `Canvas` so you are using `drawBitmap(Bitmap, Matrix, Paint)` right? so you have your matrix as the second parameter

Comment: Yes I used that. But when I apply the matrix of the first image to the second image which has high resolution. The second image is just scaled a bit, so the result image is still big (because it is high resolution than the 1st image).

Comment: so i have no idea what you really want to achieve... what are the sizes of both Bitmaps and what size do you want them to be shown?

Comment: @pskink Hi. I added a screenshot to my application sir. I also edited my explaination :)

Comment: so if your second image is 2x larger than the first and you want it to be 2x larger on the Canvas just use the same Matrix

Comment: Note. They are not the same Image resolution Sir. That is my problem

Comment: again: what are the sizes of both Bitmaps and what size do you want them to be shown? give the real numbers like: the first Bitmap is 128x128, the second is 1024x1024 and i want them to be drawn 256x256 and 521x512

Comment: first bitmap is 200x187. second bitmap is 800x750. The canvas or the screen in which to display is 590x1049. I want the second bitmap to scale that match with the first bitmap (no bitmap resizing but using only matrix) as you see them on screen/canvas. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/FEuWxgU7 this shows two different `Bitmap`s, the second one is ALWAYS drawn two times bigger, no matter how big two `Bitmap`s are

Comment: @pskink. I uploaded a photo :). See it. I think you want the second bitmap to be two times bigger, but i want it to display like the first bitmap but in real size the second bitmap is much bigger. See it :)

Comment: so i have really no idea what you want: you posted two images: one small bitmap and second two times bigger, so i gave you some code how to draw the second bitmap two times bigger, what else do you want? if you need 3 times bigger change 2f to 3f, if you want the same size change 2f to 1f

Comment: I forgot to put a label which says wrong or that is not what I'm suppose to achieved. My bad Sir. I have remove the other picture. The remaining pic will explain everything.Thank you for the code you provide. I am getting insights there.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question but only found this on google search so giving my solution:

```
    private fun applyMatrixWithDiffSize(original: Bitmap, dst: Bitmap, matrix: Matrix): Bitmap {

    //get the ratio between the images, (assuming you are keeping the aspect ratio)
    val ratio = original.width / dst.width.toFloat()

    //add scale to a new matrix to fit all changes in the new sized bitmap
    val scaleMatrix = Matrix()
    scaleMatrix.preScale(ratio, ratio)

    //pre concat so the scale gets before the rest of the changes
    matrix.preConcat(scaleMatrix)

    //create the new bitmap
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(
        dst, 0, 0,
        dst.width, dst.height, matrix, true)
}
```